# Table Header Column Sizes Change When Table Body Is Removed

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, css-tables

I have table in my html page. To make its header sticky I run a script (for some reason I'm using script) which positions the table header in the right place while scrolled. Script copies the original table. Positions the new clone table and hides(`visibility:hidden`) the clone table body.

Works fine!

But when using `visibility:hidden` browser retains the space of the table body. (You see scroll while there is nothing).

[image]

When `display:none` or table body is completely `remove()`'d from html document then table header columns' sizes do not correspond to table columns.
[image]

Any idea how to fix that?

Goal: No table hidden body and table header matching its columns.

Comment: What browsers? Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Link doesn't work for me